# <cfmail> delay between entering and email and when the email is sent

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I have a huge delay when sending email (1-2 hours) using cfmail.

Is there a setting in the Coldfusion Admin where this can be adjusted, or does the speed of the email delivery depend on many factors?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, CFMAIL creates a text file in the Mail/Spool directory in your CFroot. Then another process picks up these "spooled" files and attempts to send them in the background.

The timing of this secondary process is controlled from the Administrator on the "Mail" page.

> Spool Interval (seconds)

Check that setting first.

Note:

- if CF is set to not spool the mail, it will attempt to send mail immediately
- once CF hands off the message to the SMTP server it's out of CF's control; you'll need to dig into your mailserver logs (and those upstream)
- checking "Log all mail messages sent by ColdFusion" will be helpful to troubleshoot when email messages are actually being sent

Comment: I asked the admin to check the spool interval and it was 15 seconds...now I have to ask him to check the logs ;-0

Answer (score 1):

Which version of coldfusion you are using standard or Enterprise? If it is Standard than it has limitation to send number of emails (I guess max. 10) but for Enterprise do not have any such limitation.

Same kind of issue faced by one of my client as he was sending around 6000 emails at a time. But in my case it was normally bulk so I just schedule it to send it on off time.

Hope this help.

Comment: Good point but right now I am just testing it and it appears to have a problem sending out 1 email...hehe